# Azure Function subscription to Mail with Graph Incorrect Messages Ids

Tags: azure-functions, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a subscription with Graph to a Mailbox. I receive the notifications correctly:

```
{
    "value": [{
        "subscriptionId": "15e02ead-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3e8axx8fxx6x",
        "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2019-12-04T10:58:04.5588408+00:00",
        "tenantId": "35xx07xx-dxxx-4xxx-9xxx-dxx935xx8xxd",
        "changeType": "created",
        "resource": "Users/7xxfaxxa-9xxx-4xxx-axxx-3xxx418xxx1x/Messages/AAxxxxx2MDllxxxkLWxxxWExxxViOxxxZxxxTQ2MzkyYmFkZTQxZQBGAAAAAADssTCUod87T5Yqmkf9hREDBwD_xxxxZxxxxxxW7xxxxB9SAAAAAAExxxx_emscZ7HIQL0W7tgHpB9SAANAikGPxxxx",
        "resourceData": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Message",
            "@odata.id": "Users/7xxfaxxa-9xxx-4xxx-axxx-3xxx418xxx1x/Messages/AAxxxxx2MDllxxxkLWxxxWExxxViOxxxZxxxTQ2MzkyYmFkZTQxZQBGAAAAAADssTCUod87T5Yqmkf9hREDBwD_xxxxZxxxxxxW7xxxxB9SAAAAAAExxxx_emscZ7HIQL0W7tgHpB9SAANAikGPxxxx",
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAAD+emscZ7HIQL0W7tgHpB9SAANArs18\"",
            "id": "AAxxxxx2MDllxxxkLWxxxWExxxViOxxxZxxxTQ2MzkyYmFkZTQxZQBGAAAAAADssTCUod87T5Yqmkf9hREDBwD_xxxxZxxxxxxW7xxxxB9SAAAAAAExxxx_emscZ7HIQL0W7tgHpB9SAANAikGPxxxx"
        },
        "clientState": "secretClientValue"
    }]
}
```

But that ResourceData ID doesn't exists when I try to get it with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/.

I get all the messages for the user and the MessageId that generates the Event is different from the MessageId that I received in the event message. How is possible?